# Record Custom input text for Azure Durable Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I know how to get activity function outputs to visual studio code for Durable Functions

However, how can I do this for inputs?

I want to pass something specific to log

I dont want to log the whole input to the activity function as it could be a lot of json

This is with a .NET 7 Isolated Durable Function

The screenshot below shows the output working perfectly but no input

My code is below

```
    [Function(nameof(ProcessAllClientData))]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var clients = new List<Client>();
        for (var clientIndex = 1; clientIndex <= 200; clientIndex++)
        {
            var client = new Client()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                ClientName = $"Client - {clientIndex}",
                ClientNumber = clientIndex.ToString(),
            };
            clients.Add(client);
        }

        var outputs = new List<string>();
        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (var item in clients)
        {
            var json = item.ToJson();
            tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(ProcessClientData), json));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            outputs.Add(task.Result);
        }
        return outputs;
    }


    [Function("ProcessAllClientData_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("ProcessAllClientData_HttpStart");
        string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(ProcessAllClientData));
        logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

        // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
        return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }

    [Function(nameof(ProcessClientData))]
    public static string ProcessClientData([ActivityTrigger] string json, FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProcessClientData>(json);
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var logText = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormats.UK_DATE_TIME)} Processing Data for {data.ClientName}";
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(logText);
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("ProcessClientData");
        logger.LogInformation($"{data.ClientName} delaying for 5 seconds - simulating processing");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        logger.LogInformation($"{data.ClientName} delaying for 5 seconds - Processing complete");
        logText = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormats.UK_DATE_TIME)} Completed Processing for {data.ClientName}";
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(logText);
        var result = stringBuilder.ToString().RemoveTrailingCrlf();
        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Paul